# How do I do more than one thing in Excel If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

In Excel I have a field, lets say F4, that checks if F3 contains the letter x.
If it does then F4 must be the same as J10 else just 0.

And thats no problem, I can do that.
But at the same time I set F4 to be the same value as J10 I want to increment the value in J10.

If J10's value is 5, then I want my If statement to put 5 in F4 and increment the value in J10 to 6.

Is that possible?

Comment: To do just that: 
F4 `=IF(COUNTIF(F3,"*x*"),J10-1,0)`
J10 `=IF(COUNTIF(F3,"*x*"),5+1,5)`

But if you want something more dynamic you may need some sheet code instead of formulas.

Comment: ...if you do want the change in F4 to directly control J10, then that's a circular reference.

Comment: Your solution is kind off working.

Comment: Your solution is kind of working, when remove the "-1" part. 
But I think i explained it wrong.  

Here's an exampel: 
J10 = 5. 
If F3 = x then G3 must be 5, and J10 must become 6
J10 = 6, 
If F4 = x then G4 must be 6, and J10 must become 7
J10 = 7, 
If F5 = x then G5 must be 7, and J10 must become 8

I hope this explains my problem more clearly,

Answer (score 0):

G3    = 5
you can put the starting value you want in another cell and set G3 = to that so you can change it at the top level

G4   =IF(F4="x",G3+1,"")

Drag G4 Down

J10   =MAX((G3:G9))+1